# Deletion from root in a 2-3 tree

Tags: tree, 2-3-tree

i have the following 2-3 Tree:

```
                           <L>
    <E>                                        <R>
 D       I                                P          X,Y
```

i need to delete "L" and then "X" from it, but i cant find material regarding deletion from a root.

thank you!

Comment: Does this help:
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/10.23TREE.html#delete

Comment: ye it did, thank you!